# adding different language strings to a single resource file

Tags: c#, localization, resources, managed, resx

I have a small application, which includes a resource (.resx) file.

This file contains an icon, and a string, which is used by another application. The icon will be displayed on a button, and the string is the mouseover text.

What I want is in some way, to add strings in multiple languages, without having to crate additional .resx files.

Is there any way to do this?

I am writing my application in C#, and I would like to keep it in the .Net environment, and keep the resource managed.

Any help is appreciated - thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want different resource files for different languages ? That's the recommended way of doing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be an abuse of the way localization works in .net. It is meant to work like that - you create a resource file AND localized resource files containing `.languageid.` in the middle.

Of course, you can code your own "reader" method which appends some prefix to the resource name and then save several values in your file (for instance `lv-formtitle`, `en-formtitle`, `ru-formtitle` etc) , but - why?

If the problem is you do not want to copy the icon to several resource files - make 2 resources, one for icons, other for strings. Localize only the one containing strings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I will go with making two resource files.

Comment: Sometimes you have to localise icons, too.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can add more strings to your resource file, but they will have to have a different name and managed in your application that way (for example - "title" and "title-he") .

Doing this however, defeats the point of resource files.

You should use additional resource files, one per locale, even though you don't want to...

Comment: I can understand that several resource files is the way to go - and why go against best practise ;)

Thanks a lot for replying all of you :)